# Detect first visibility in a Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

I'm manipulating a global macro, say `\mytext`, that I print on every slide.  I would like to incrementally add data to that macro in a natural way:

```
\frame{
  MyText: \mytext

  \gappto\mytext{One}\pause
  \gappto\mytext{Two}\pause
  \gappto\mytext{Three}\pause
}
```

Of course, as the frame is evaluated each time, this won't work.  Now, I could test that the current frame is the last paused one, leading to the following working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\mytext{}

\makeatletter
\def\addtotext#1{%
  \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe = \c@beamerpauses
  \gappto\mytext{#1}
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{
  MyText: \mytext

  \addtotext{One}\pause
  \addtotext{Two}\pause
  \addtotext{Three}\pause
}
\end{document}
```

**Question:** How to extend this example so that it works with any `\only<>` or `\visible<>`?  I'm in a specific case where every added part to `\mytext` is unique; thus if the addition is evaluated multiple times, I can simply check (using e.g. lists) that I've not already added said text.

Comment: I noticed that `\mytext` is "off" by one frame because the set value is only used on the next frame (i. e. in this example, the first frame is empty, "One" actually ends up on the second frame, "Two" on the "third" etc.). Is that intentional, or would you actually like to have "One" directly on the first frame?

Comment: It's by design; this is not something I mind, and I'd guess that it would take quite a lot of effort to keep the same code and have the effect you mention.  Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following answer, the main idea of which is to patch `pgfsys@{begin,end}invisible` to count the amount of nesting within it.  The first time `\addtomytext` is executed with a 0 invisibility nesting, I assume that it is visible.  To ensure that something is not added twice to `\mytext`, I store everything added in a list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{beamer@invisibilitydepth}
\preto\pgfsys@begininvisible{\global\addtocounter{beamer@invisibilitydepth}{1}}
\preto\pgfsys@endinvisible{\global\addtocounter{beamer@invisibilitydepth}{-1}}

\def\mytext{}
\def\arg@list{}
\newbool{is@found}
\newcommand<>{\addtomytext}[1]{%
  \long\def\do##1{\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\setbool{is@found}{true}\listbreak}{}}%
  \only#2{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{beamer@invisibilitydepth}}{0}{%
      \boolfalse{is@found}%
      \dolistloop{\arg@list}%
      \ifbool{is@found}{}{%
        \listgadd{\arg@list}{#1}%
        \gappto\mytext{#1}}%
    }{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{
  MyText: \mytext

  \visible<4->{\addtomytext{Four}\only<5>{\addtomytext{Fiveprime}}}
  \addtomytext{One}\pause
  \addtomytext{Two}\pause
  \addtomytext{Three}\pause
  \pause
  \addtomytext{Five}\pause
}
\end{document}
```

Any comment on the method and its cleanliness is welcome.